# MySQL InnoDB Reset Existing Auto-Increment Records

Tags: mysql, innodb, auto-increment

Using MySQL Workbench, I have a MySQL InnoDB with a few hundred records.

The `records` table has the following format (`id` is `auto_increment` and `unique`);

```
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
| 2500 | jo    |
+------+-------+
| 2511 | jim   |
+------+-------+
| 2512 | sarah |
+------+-------+
| 2513 | jane  |
+------+-------+
```

Notice my first record begins at 2500. Presumably this is because I have dropped and re-imported the table data numerous times.

Is there any way I can 'reset' the `id` field so that the records begin at 1 and not 2500?

I want the table to look like this:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | jo    |
+----+-------+
| 2  | jim   |
+----+-------+
| 3  | sarah |
+----+-------+
| 4  | jane  |
+----+-------+
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This is possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15933173/how-to-reset-id-from-auto-incremment-in-innodb-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tbl;
```

If that does not work,

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

But you should not depend on the actual values of `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  There are many things that can make it non-reproducible.